# Difficulty moving from electric to groovy - bullet issues

Tags: ros, bullet, ros-electric, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to upgrade a system from electric to groovy.  Unfortunately, I'm getting stuck since the codebase uses btQuaternion.

The short version though is, I can't find the migration script mentioned here: http://ros.org/wiki/geometry/bullet_migration

My tf folder has no scripts with that name.  All I have are:
static_transform_publisher
tf_change_notifier
tf_echo
tf_empty_listener
tf_monitor

What happened to the conversion script?  Was it removed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66348/difficulty-moving-from-electric-to-groovy---bullet-issues/) by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not being installed into groovy.  You can get it directly from the source https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/groovy-devel/tf/scripts/bullet_migration_sed.py

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on 2013-07-01**:
Is there anything I'll have to do set-up wise other than just running this script?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-01**:
Change to the directory you want to modify.  It's good practice to make sure you don't have any local changes in your source control so you can check the diff and rollback if it doesn't work as you want.

**Comment by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on 2013-07-01**:
Okay...it messed up a little bit but with tiny changes it then worked.  Thanks!